# Can I convert my front intermediate light (with only 1 wire) to a junction box with live, neutral and ground wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I want to change my entire front light housing because it is old and uses an intermediate-base light bulb. The new one I have purchased has black, white and copper wires. The old one only has a wire go straight to the bulb base and has no junction box. Can I convert this myself or do I need to hire an electrician?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. There is probably 1 wire leaving the fixture and 1 wire leaving it. These would be black and white, but on old old wiring the insulation may have discolored.

Comment: At a minimum you need liquid tight EMT and junction box, no exposed wires are permitted. If the house wiring has no grounding, I'm not sure you're required to provide such to make a small repair.

Comment: That cable looks like lamp cord, Where does it go after passing through the wall?  Do you want to change the entire fixture (the whole metal box and all), or just the lamp holder (the bit that holds the bulb)?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Yes I think is a lamp cord and I don't know where the cable goes since behind the wall.  I want to change the entire fixture if possible 'coz that thing looks ancient and I do want to put on an LED bulb instead.  Is it hard to do or do I need to hire an electrician?

Comment: What is on the other side of the wall?  How is this light turned on, does it plugged in, or is it switch controlled?

Comment: There's a switch that turns on and cut off all the front lights and outlets power.